# Remove "turn off adblock" ad wrapper on news page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I read news on this Norwegian news site "www.vg.no" everyday. The other day I read it on my school computer which had adblock installed and I noticed that the ads were removed, all though an ad wrapper saying "turn off adblock etc" popped up instead. As I'm studying information technology in school I decided to take it on as a side project to make a chrome extension which completely removes those ad wrappers.

I made an extension and used a content_script which called a script once the page loaded. I called it `script.js`

So when the page loads, my script gets run. My script looks like this:

```
var element = document.querySelector('div.ad-wrapper');
element.parentElement.removeChild(element);
```

This works great, but then I encountered a new problem. The div which wraps around the ad wrapper changes name on every page load. I found a script on the site which randomizes the div class name every page load.

It looks like this:

```
<script>
window.__AB__ = function() {
    var dummy = Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, 5),
        css = dummy + '.' + dummy + '{' + 'display: block;' + 'position: absolute;' + 'top: 0;' + 'left: -180px;' + 'width: 180px;' + 'height: 700px;' + 'background: #19C url(//1.vgc.no/img/vgab.png) no-repeat bottom;' + 'color: #FFF;' + 'line-height: 1.4em;' + '}' + dummy + '.' + dummy + ' .t1 {' + 'padding: 260px 10px 67px;' + 'font-size: 18px;' + '}' + dummy + '.' + dummy + ' .t2 {' + 'padding: 0 451px 0 11px;' + 'margin: 0;' + 'font-size: 18px;' + '}' + dummy + '.' + dummy + ' h1 {' + 'margin: 0 0 16px;' + 'padding: 18px 11px 0;' + 'font-size: 26px;' + 'font-weight: normal;' + '}' + dummy + '.' + dummy + ' .zwei {' + 'padding: 11px 40px;' + 'position: absolute;' + 'right: 11px;' + 'top: 81px;' + 'background-color: #FFF;' + 'border: 1px solid #227196;' + 'color: #D00;' + 'font-size: 18px;' + 'text-transform: uppercase;' + '}' + dummy + '.' + dummy + ' button {' + 'padding: 11px 0;' + 'margin: 0 10px;' + 'background-color: #FFF;' + 'border: 1px solid #227196;' + 'color: #D00;' + 'font-size: 18px;' + 'text-align: center;' + 'font-weight: normal;' + 'width: auto;' + 'text-transform: uppercase;' + 'height: auto;' + 'line-height: 1.2em;' + '}' + '.tablet .reg-grid-main .ad[class*=smartboard], .desktop .reg-grid-main .ad[class*=smartboard], .tablet .reg-grid-main .ad[class*=netboard], .desktop .reg-grid-main .ad[class*=netboard] { min-height: auto; }',
        text = '<p class="t1"> Ved å skru på annonser, hjelper du å finansiere tidkrevende og viktig journalistikk. </p>',
        topText = ' <h1>Hei, kjære VG-leser!</h1><p class="t2">Vi har oppdaget at du blokkerer annonser. Vi i VG hadde satt stor pris på om du hvitlister oss slik at vi kan finansiere vår journalistikk med reklame og fortsette å være en gratis nyhetskilde.</p>',
        browser;
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') > -1 ? true : false) {
        browser = 'firefox';
    } else {
        browser = 'chrome';
    }
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    if (style.styleSheet) {
        style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
    } else {
        style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    }
    var left = document.createElement(dummy);
    left.className = dummy;
    left.innerHTML = '<!--googleoff: index-->' + text + '<!--googleon: index-->';
    var right = left.cloneNode(true);
    right.style.right = '-180px';
    right.style.left = 'auto';
    var topEl = right.cloneNode();
    topEl.style.position = 'relative';
    topEl.style.right = 'auto';
    topEl.style.width = '100%';
    topEl.style.height = '150px';
    topEl.style.marginTop = '-1px';
    topEl.style.backgroundImage = 'none';
    topEl.innerHTML = '<!--googleoff: index-->' + topText + '<!--googleon: index-->';
    var open = function(e) {
        var pop = document.createElement('div'),
            dim = 1000,
            over = document.createElement('div'),
            btn = document.createElement('a');

        function close(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            btn.removeEventListener('click', close);
            pop.parentNode.removeChild(pop);
            over.parentNode.removeChild(over);
            return false;
        }
        btn.addEventListener('click', close);
        pop.style.cssText = 'width:' + dim + 'px; height: auto; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; background-color: #fff; padding: 10px; margin-left: -' + (dim / 2) + 'px; margin-top:-390px;z-index: 2000;';
        over.style.cssText = 'width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; background-color: #000; z-index: 1999; opacity: .8;';
        over.addEventListener('click', close);
        var popText = '<h3>Slik skrur du på annonser</h3>';
        if (browser === 'chrome') {
            popText += '<div style="float: left; margin-right: 16px; padding-right: 16px; border-right: 2px solid #19C;"><p><strong>For Adblock</strong></p>';
            popText += '<img src="//1.vgc.no/ab/chrome-1.png"><br>';
            popText += '<img src="//1.vgc.no/ab/chrome-2.png"></div>';
            popText += '<p><strong>For Adblock Plus</strong></p>';
            popText += '<img src="//1.vgc.no/ab/chrome-plus.png">';
        } else if (browser === 'firefox') {
            popText += '<div style="text-align: center;"><p><strong>For Adblock Plus</strong></p>';
            popText += '<img src="//1.vgc.no/ab/firefox.png"></div>';
        }
        popText += '<div style="text-align: center; padding: 20px 0; clear: both;"><strong>Takk for at du skrur på annonser på VG.no :-)</strong></div>';
        pop.innerHTML = popText;
        btn.innerHTML = 'Lukk';
        btn.className = 'close';
        btn.href = '#';
        document.body.appendChild(pop);
        pop.appendChild(btn);
        document.body.appendChild(over);
        return false;
    };
    var topBoard = document.querySelector('#ad-topboard, #ad-front-topboard');
    if (topBoard) {
        topBoard.style.display = 'none';
    }
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.addEventListener('click', open);
    btn.className = 'action-click';
    btn.setAttribute('data-stats-type', 'exit');
    btn.setAttribute('data-stats-string', 'Adblock::OpenPopup');
    btn.innerHTML = 'Skru på annonser';
    left.appendChild(btn);
    var btn2 = btn.cloneNode(true);
    btn2.addEventListener('click', open);
    right.appendChild(btn2);
    var btn3 = btn.cloneNode(true);
    btn3.addEventListener('click', open);
    btn3.className = 'zwei';
    topEl.appendChild(btn3);
    document.head.appendChild(style);
    var con = document.querySelector('.reg-grid-container');
    con.appendChild(right);
    con.appendChild(left);
    if (con.insertAdjacentElement) {
        con.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', topEl);
    } else {
        con.insertBefore(topEl, con.firstChild)
    }
    if (window.xt_med) {
        window.xt_med('C', 0, 'Adblock::Enabled', 'N');
    }
    (window.dablockTrigger = window.dablockTrigger || []).push('survey');
    window.__AB__ = function() {};
};
</script>
```

Basically they are making a variable named dummy and giving it a random-generated name. So my question to you, here on stackoverflow, is, how can I get the class name of the div so that I can delete it? I feel it would be possible to convert the whole side script into string and then search for the dummy variable and then remove that script or something? Also, inside the div wrapping the ad, I see a paragraph `<p class="t1">` and I tried to remove the parent which is the random generated name div but no luck. Any ideas?

Edit:

I tried calling the script in the manifest.json file once the root html has been loaded, so calling the script before `<head>` is created, but any changes I do before the site loads will most likely get overridden once the rest of the page loads right? Is there a way to make an uneditable function? for an example testfunction = function(){} and then in another script when they try to run testfunction = function(){var element = random} they dont override that function which was already declared?

Comment: Can you not just do `window.__AB__ = function(){};` to change the function to nothing before it's called?

Comment: I tried doing that, But I think the scripts on the page runs before my script runs. As the extension I made uses a content script it runs after the page has fully loaded if im not wrong. 
This is my manifest.json file for the extension:

"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://www.vg.no/"],
        "js": ["script.js"]
    }
]

Comment: Does this help? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost been 2 years, but since then I have taught myself javascript + a whole bunch more stuff, and decided to do another take at this project. It basically took me less than 10 minutes coming up with a solution, and that solution is fairly simple.

I just completely ignored their "dummy" script and removed the 3 first div children elements of the container div. This is not the best solution as it is a little hard-coded. Anyways works like a charm though. So now I have a working extension :D

If anyone is interested, here is the simple .js code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
var topAdWrapper = document.querySelector(".reg-grid-container");

for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    topAdWrapper.removeChild(topAdWrapper.childNodes[0]);
}

var body = document.querySelector("body");
body.style.backgroundImage = "";
});
```